# 6v High Torque Servo Won't Function On Motor Shield?

Tags: arduino-uno, power, servo, arduino-motor-shield, voltage

[image: circuit diagram here]

I have only ever been able to get this servo to “somewhat” work when connected to 5v pin on the shield, the ground on the shield, and the signal line attached to whatever pin. But 5v is not enough and 9v is too much. I'm trying a million different ways to power this thing, but I don't understand why I give it an appropriate voltage from X source (while still having the signal line connected of course), and it doesn't want to move at all.

So currently my Arduino is powered via USB. The shield/motor is powered from a 12v 2a power supply, which with a simple voltage divider circuit gets me 6.29V. Multimeter seems to show this works. Also the “Vin Connect” jumper on back was cut to make the screw terminals a dedicated power line for the motor, per Arduino website. I tried this set up without cutting the jumper too, same - no result.

Can anyone help me out? All I want to do is power my arduino with shield, and motor, however that has to happen, and be able to run the "Servo Sweep" example code.

https://docs.arduino.cc/hardware/motor-shield-rev3

[https://www.amazon.com/ANNIMOS-Digital-Voltage-Stainless-Waterproof/dp/B07KTSCN4J](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KTSCN4J)

Comment: Hints: ohms law, voltage divider without and with load (also take into account different modes of operation).  For example expected impedance when servo takes 2A ->  R = U/I = 6V/2A = 3Ohm. Your voltage divider ratio 2000 : 2.9955 ( (12V / 2002.9955) * 2.9955 = 17.9mV (if you just replace servo with "equivalent" resistor, not with real servo)

Answer (score 0):

It may pay to think about current required as well as voltage. Looking at a data sheet I found online ([data sheet link)](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81EFGw8qkhL.pdf) it refers to a stall current of 3.5A when running at 6V.

What do you mean by “somewhat”? Can you give more detail on the behavior you see? It may be useful to hook your multimeter up as an ammeter to get an idea of whether current draw is approaching the limit of the wall plug (2A) used.

Comment: The gauge of wire and the power rating of the resistors used in the voltage divider will also impact the available current.

Comment: It would be useful to add photographs or a circuit diagram; as well as your code; and observed behavior to your question.

Comment: I’m not sure what function you’re expecting from the Motor shield? I believe it may be extraneous. My understanding is that you need connections of: 6V 4A supply + and - to servo. Shared ground and PWM signal from Arduino to servo, separate USB power to Arduino. Motor shield not required. Any comments from other readers?

Comment: Thank you for all your ideas. Yes perhaps the Amperage is the main culprit here. The wires are quite thin also, something that never occurred to me. - "a stall current of 3.5A when running at 6V" does this mean that I need more than 3.5A to move it at all? That makes sense to me EXCEPT the fact that it does perform a 180 degree sweep with the 5V onboard plugin, powered soley through USB. I would just naturally assume the USB does not have that kind of amps. When I say "somewhat" I mean, I can get it to move, but it lacks the advertised torque - by a lot. Can't lift nearly enough.

Comment: Stall current is the maximum current drawn, when the motor is applying its maximum torque, either because it is being prevented from moving entirely or because it can no longer accelerate given the load it is under. https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/613/what-is-stall-current-and-free-current-of-motors#:~:text=Short%20answer,the%20load%20it%20is%20under.